# Android sense knocks

Tags: android, sensors

I'm prototyping a sensor read app. It reads out the sensors at a given interval, let's say every 30 seconds, and I want to add a special marker via knocking on the device.

Example: Let's say I finished grocery shopping and want to log that fact in the application.

I **don't want** to take out my phone, turn on the screen, open an app and find a huge button to click it on order to add a marker in time.

I **want** to knock the bones of my fingers twice on the phone to make the app create a mark while it is in my pocket. I want to knock on it twice to add a "here happened this"-mark (you'll remember what it was), knock it five times to add a "THIS IS WHAT YOU DON'T WANT TO FORGET"-mark which will also send you an email at that moment.

This is the kind of sensor logging I'm talking about, those are two devices. In those graphs I would like to add those significant markers.

[image]

How can I archieve this?

Comment: Have you read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html?

Comment: I have used that in part for developing the prototype. There's nothing in there.